# nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "match", why does it appear?

Tags: nginx

this is my config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wArZ.png)

```
log_format mqtt '$remote_addr [$time_local] $protocol $status $bytes_received ' 
                '$bytes_sent $upstream_addr';

upstream hive_mq {
    server 192.168.11.200:1883; #node1
    server 127.0.0.1:1883; #node2
    zone tcp_mem 64k;
}

match mqtt_conn {
        # Send CONNECT packet with client ID "nginx health check"
        send   \x10\x20\x00\x06\x4d\x51\x49\x73\x64\x70\x03\x02\x00\x3c\x00\x12\x6e\x67\x69\x6e\x78\x20\x68\x65\x61\x6c\x74\x68\x20\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b;
        expect \x20\x02\x00\x00; # Entire payload of CONNACK packet
}

server {
    listen 8081;
    proxy_pass hive_mq;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
    health_check match=mqtt_conn;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mqtt_access.log mqtt;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mqtt_error.log; # Health check notifications
}
```

but when I reload the setting and it return failed as following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8xVL.png)

```
 nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-12-02 03:20:49 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 51793 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 51821 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 51819 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 51794 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Dec 02 03:20:49 localhost systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Dec 02 03:20:49 localhost nginx[51821]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "match" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:171
Dec 02 03:20:49 localhost nginx[51821]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Dec 02 03:20:49 localhost systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 02 03:20:49 localhost systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 02 03:20:49 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

noted I have include modules/*.conf and the modules are
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4VQp.png)

Do I miss someting?

How to address the config problem in Nginx?

Comment: Are you using the commercial version of Nginx or the free version?

Answer (score 0):

The Nginx commercial license does not allow adding this type of directive.
I recommend to try with Nginx Plus.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ." I could not and only turned it into a much too brief "I recommend ..." answer. Better improve it.

Comment: Your answer does not really solve the author's problem. Please avoid putting such an answer. Instead, use a comment and THEN post an answer after the author accepted your "fact".